# Unstaged Commits After Deleting Branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have this branch that I worked on for a bit then handed off to someone else to finish.  Now the branch is finished.

I checked into the branch and pulled.  It said that I was ahead of /origin/branchname by a few commits.  Figuring I probably had some unpushed commits, I checked out to another branch and deleted the offending branch with `git branch -D branchname`

I then checked back into the branch and pulled, and it still says that I'm ahead by those commits.  I don't remember this sort of situation happening before, so I didn't think this is normal git behavior.

Any way of getting that branch to be exactly what's pushed to remote, not caring about unpushed commits?

Comment: What do you mean that you "then checked back into the branch and pulled"? After `git branch -D branchname`, the branch should no longer exist.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here either.  I do `git branch-D branchname` and it says it's deleted.  I can then checkout into the branch doing `git checkout branchname`  When I do `git branch` it isn't listed either.

Comment: After `git branch -D`, if you do `git branch -a`, does the branch show up?

Comment: Nope.  I see the branch under the `remotes/origin/branchname`, but not locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting on this as the cause:

```
$ git checkout -b work
# work work work
$ git push origin work:work    # hand off to someone else
# pause for a day or whatever

# come back, find that someone else finished the work
$ git pull origin work
... the usual git pull messages ...
```

At this point git says you're `ahead 3`, say (the other person made 3 more commits).  So you do this:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git branch -D work
$ git checkout work
Branch work set up to track remote branch work from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'work'
$ git pull origin work
```

Here's where things keep going wrong.  The command: `git pull origin work` does in fact go out to remote `origin` and pick up the new commits.  Those new commits go into your repository, and are merged into local branch `work` ... but under current (pre-1.9) versions of git, `origin/work` is not updated, *even though the origin's `work` label is newer*.

In other words, your local git is getting the new information about `origin/work`, but git pull *throws it away* after updating the *local* branch.  Then things like `git status` tell you you're "3 ahead", because the `origin/work` your git has recorded in your repository is all stale.

When (while on some other branch) you delete the local `work` branch, then `git checkout work`, it re-creates your local branch based on your still-obsolete idea of where `origin` is.  A subsequent `git pull origin work` again brings over any new commits and merges them into the local `work` branch again, but again fails to update `origin/work`.

This is to be fixed in git 1.9/2.0, but for now, you just need to use `git fetch origin` to update the `origin/...` branch names.  Avoid `git pull` and you avoid this particular trap.  (Or, update to the newer git once it's out.)

(I prefer separating out the `git fetch` and `git merge` steps anyway, although there's definitely something to be said for convenience, if only it worked. :-) )

Comment: This was exactly the issue.  These are the steps I took to get it to work: `git checkout someotherbranch`, `git branch -D branchname`, `git fetch origin branchname:branchname`, `git checkout branchname`  At this point I did another `git fetch origin branchname:branchname`, though it didn't seem to do anything.  Subsequent `git pull origin branchname` seemed to be synced with what is stored remotely.  Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question

> Any way of getting that branch to be exactly what's pushed to remote, not caring about unpushed commits?

you can `git pull --force`. From the documentation:

```
-f, --force
    When git fetch is used with <rbranch>:<lbranch> refspec, it refuses
    to update the local branch <lbranch> unless the remote branch
    <rbranch> it fetches is a descendant of <lbranch>. This option
    overrides that check.
```

You may have to fully specify the branches, e.g. `git pull --force origin branchname:branchname`, assuming a remote of `origin`.

Having said that, it's probably a good idea to figure out what's causing this problem.

If you `git fetch origin branchname`, you should now be able to compare `branchname` and `origin/branchname` using `gitk`, or `git log --all --graph --decorate`, `git log origin/branchname...branchname`, or any number of other ways. This should get you started down the path of figuring out what's actually wrong.